# update_post_meta not working in plugin

Tags: post-meta

I am trying to update post meta for a voting plugin. Specifically it calls `update_post_meta()` on an ajax request. Here is the code:

```
function add_settings_menu() {
     add_options_page('Contested Settings', 'Contested Settings', 1, 'manage_options', 'contested_settings');
}

function contested_settings() {
    include("contested_admin_settings.php");
}

function get_posts_votes($post) {
    $votes = get_post_meta($post, 'votes', true );
    return $votes;
}

function add_contested_voting($category, $post) {
    if (in_category($category, $post)) {
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
            $post = get_post($post);
            $post_id = (int)$post->ID;
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'votes', '0', true);
            /*if($votes == '') { 
                update_post_meta($post, 'votes', '0'); 
                $votes = get_post_meta( $post, 'votes', true ); 
            }*/
        ?>
            <form id='voting-form'>
                <strong>Vote now!</strong><br />
                <label id='votes'><?php echo get_posts_votes($post); ?></label>
                <input type='button' id='vote_up' value='+1' />
            </form>
            <script>
                $(function() {
                    ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
                    $("#vote_up").click(function() {
                        var data = {
                            action: 'contested',
                            votes: '<?php echo $votes; ?>',
                            post: '<?php echo $post_id; ?>'
                        };
                        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(data) { 
                            $("#voting-form").html(data);
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
        <?
    }
}

function ajax_posted() {
    $votes_plus = $_POST['votes']+1;
    $id = $_POST['post'];
    if (update_post_meta($id, 'votes', $votes_plus)) {
        $votes_ret = get_post_meta($id, 'votes', true);
        echo "Thanks for voting! ".$votes_ret." vote.";
    } else {
        echo "Voting failed!";
    }
    die();
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'add_settings_menu');
add_action('wp_ajax_contested', 'ajax_posted');
```

I'm not really sure what is wrong with this. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're entirely too trusting of your `$_POST` variable.  Please [sanitize your data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation). (I know this doesn't answer your question, but building good habits now will save you grief later.)

Comment: Is your troublesome `update_post_meta()` the one in the `if( $votes == '' )` statement?  If so, I don't see where `$votes` is getting initialized, so I think you're comparing a `null` to an empty string.

Comment: I know I need to sanitize the `$_POST` variable, just trying to figure this out first. :) 

And no the troublesome one is in the ajax_posted() variable. It is returning true and echoing the value just like it should. I cant determine if the variable is getting over written somewhere else or if the update post that says its workign really isn't.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Something was wrong with using '$id' in update_post_meta.

I changed this:

```
function ajax_posted() {
    $votes_plus = $_POST['votes']+1;
    $id = $_POST['post'];
    if (update_post_meta($id, 'votes', $votes_plus)) {
        $votes_ret = get_post_meta($id, 'votes', true);
        echo "Thanks for voting! ".$votes_ret." vote.";
    } else {
        echo "Voting failed!";
    }
    die();
}
```

to this:

```
function ajax_posted() {
    $id = intval($_POST['post']);
    $post = get_post($id);
    $votes = get_posts_votes($post);
    $votes_plus = $votes+1;
    if (update_post_meta($post, 'votes', $votes_plus)) {
        $votes_ret = get_post_meta($id, 'votes', true);
        echo "Thanks for voting! ".$votes_ret." vote.";
    } else {
        echo "Voting failed!";
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: I AM voting up for finding and solving ur problem and updated in the stackexchange.